# How to ban object creation for a class without terminating the program?

Tags: python, class, oop, python-3.x, object

So I'm currently learning python and I was wondering if there was a way to have a class be a superclass for others without allowing objects to be directly created from it. I tried removing the constructor method but that doesn't stop the instantiation it only makes the object blank, I've also tried raising errors but that terminates the program, which I don't want to do, and technically it doesn't prevent the instantiation it just makes the object inaccessible by terminating the program. i.e.:

```
class MySuperClass():
    def __init__(self):
        raise Exception("Cannot create object directly from base class")
```

I've also tried trying then raising an exception within it

```
try:
    class MySuperClass():
        def __init__(self):
            raise ValueError
except:
    print("Cannot create object directly from base class")
```

which still doesn't stop the object creation, I've also tried putting this line in the constructor `del self` but it doesn't seem to have any effect. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? How about a docstring "Think three times before instantiating this class."? It's Python, after all.

Comment: If you are trying to require that subclasses implement a method, use the `abc` module

Comment: What do you want it to do instead of stopping the program?  If someone does `x = MySuperClass()` and then tries to do something with `x` (like call some other method on it), what do you want to happen?

Comment: Instead of creating it print that they shouldn't and move on to run the rest of the program

Comment: @MarwanSabry: You can't do that, though.  If "the rest of the program" relies on `x` existing, you can't run the rest of the program.  In general you can't just skip ahead to later operations without completing earlier ones, because when people create an object they expect to be able to use it, so the program will just fail later when it turns out they can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python classes have a `__new__` method which is called when you create an instance and returns the instance. Thus, the following code will work.

```
class MySuperClass(object):
    def __new__(cls,*args):
        if cls is MySuperClass:
            return None
        return object.__new__(cls,*args)
```

Any attempt to create an instance of `MySuperClass` will instead give you `None`. Subclasses can be instatiated however.